# netapi32.dll - searching for certain instruction

Tags: windows, security, debugging, winapi

I'm trying to figure out how the Unhandled Exception Filter heap overflow works. I pretty much know what is supposed to happen, but I need to find the instruction "call dword ptr[edi+0x78]" in netapi32.dll.

Can you help me find that instruction. I tried to use ollydbg, I Loaded the netapi32.dll and searched for a command, then inputted "call dword ptr[edi+0x78]", but nothing.

Is there more effective way for searching such instructions?

Comment: @eleanor Thanks. I don't know the answer to your question. Perhaps you could explain what leads you to netapi32.dll and call dword ptr[edi+0x78]

Comment: BTW: I found a way to search through modules using ollydbg. The problem was that the command you're looking for has to be typed exactly as the debugger presents it. Maybe a better way would be to also support regular expressions. So I mark this solved for now.

Comment: @eleanor You should add an answer to your question and then accept it if you managed to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with ollydbg is that whenever searching for a command you have to type exactly as the debugger presents the command (no regular expressions allowed). This is the line that I used:

```
call dword ptr ds:[edi+78]
```

it works now.